# Emacs depends on perl

Tags: emacs

Why does emacs depend on Perl? I thought it is all based on C/Lisp?

Emacs Version 24.1.4.fc17

(Working on a fresh out of the box fedora17)

Comment: This question is distribution specific. In Arch Linux f.i., emacs does not depend directly on perl.

Comment: @user99383 are you sure? Arch will install perl by default so you might just not have noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a dependency because `perl-mode.el` and `cperl-mode.el` have been built-in to Emacs for quite some time, and these modes will not work properly if Perl is not installed on the system.

These files can be found in the Emacs git repository under the directory:

`emacs.git/plain/lisp/progmodes/`

Comment: That sounds really bad to be forced to install Perl just because Emacs **supports** it. Anyway, thanks for the answer.